# SQL Server : multiple rows ignoring some and returning others

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Good afternoon folks,

I have a database table which contains data about sickness for employees. It looks like this.

```
Date                     ID        State
2013-05-03 00:00:00      0002371   Working
2013-05-03 00:00:00      0002622   Working
2013-05-03 00:00:00      0005590   Working
2013-05-03 00:00:00      0005590   Sick
```

if you'll notice ID `00005590` has two entries, one for working (they were scheduled to) then another to say they phoned in sick. So if I query the database for that user I get two rows or results.

What I'd like to do is only return the sick row if the person was sick and ignore their working result, so I end up with...

```
Date                     ID        State
2013-05-03 00:00:00      0002371   Working
2013-05-03 00:00:00      0002622   Working
2013-05-03 00:00:00      0005590   Sick
```

I'm running SQL Server 2005.

Any ideas ladies and gents?

Much appreciated.

D

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `row_number()` and `case`:

```
select [date], id, state
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by (case when state = 'Sick' then 1 else 0 end) desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

What this does is assign a sequential number to each `id` (based on the `partition by` clause).  A row that contains "sick" is assigned the value of 1 (if present); otherwise, the "working" row will be assigned 1.  The filter only takes the first row.

Note that this returns only one row per id.  If you could have multiple "working" or "sick" rows, then you can use `rank()` instead of `row_number()`.